# what is dimens.xml(w820dp) in android studio.?

Tags: android, android-studio, dimensions

Upon creating the new project in android studio in the following path were created two xml files by default.

```
..res/values/dimens.xml
..res/values/dimens.xml(w820dp)
```

Am aware of the file **dimens.xml** where we can define the dimensions for the elements, but why the second file **dimens.xml(w820dp)** created by default.

Can someone please shed lights on why it is needed and when we can use it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 7):

You can define several folders for each desired screensize in Andorid Studio. In your case, android studio defines **values** folders where you define dimensions (measurements) for scaling tablets or phones.
E.g. it defines two **values** folders like:

```
values-large
values-xlarge
```

or in your case

```
values-w820dp
```

Now inside this folders, a **dimen.xml** file is defined, where you can put your measurements in (unit dp) for the corresponding screensize.
Define a measurement like this:

```
<dimen name="value1">17dp</dimen>
```

Then embedd this sizes in your layout xml, like:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/value1"
```

Depending on the screensize, the system will load the correct measurements from this folders, e.g. if you have a screen size **large** only the defined values in folder **values-large** will be loaded.
For more information, also have a look at https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html

EDIT1: So basically if you see the file **dimen.xml(w820dp)**, the values in there are only used, if the app is executed on displays with 820dp and above, in this case, it means tablets.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have not file named `..res/values/dimens.xml(w820dp)` at all in your project structure (check yourself). What you have instead is `..res/values-w820dp/dimens.xml` file but to make editing right file easier, Android studio will (in `Android` view) show it as such. This file will be used by the framework on devices with display width 820dp or higher:

> Specifies a minimum available screen width, in dp units at which the
>   resource should be used—defined by the  value. This configuration
>   value will change when the orientation changes between landscape and
>   portrait to match the current actual width.

On other, "plain" `dimens.xml` will be loaded. See [Providing Alternative Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) documentation on resource qualifiers to find out more about possible options and benefits.

Answer (score 0):

**Main use case of these files is to Support variety screen resolutions for user interface**

**dimens.xml**

```
Android automatically take values from this file for device with dpi less than 820dp
```

**dimens.xml(w820dp)**

```
Android automatically take values from this file for device with dpi greater than 820dp
```

**How to use**

Declare dimension in these files with same name(**dimens.xml**)

```
<dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height">40dp</dimen>
```

Change only in their values (**dimens.xml(w820dp)**)

```
<dimen name="button_width">400dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height">80dp</dimen>
```

**w820dp**

```
 for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This would include 7"
 and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively)
```

Comment: what happens if the dpi is exactly 820

Answer (score 0):

`w820dp` is a **qualifier value** to provide alternate values for different dimensions. This is used to localize to device types properly.